# Invoke async Task in abstract class via Reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asynchronous

I'm trying to run tasks async by using reflection. The problem is that the class is abstract. I got this to work with `InvokeMember` in a synchronous context. With async the method is not found for some reason.. So this is what I came up with instead. It's not working because I can't pass an object of an abstract class to the Invoke method.. dead end?

```
public MyClass
{
  public async Task<string> MyMethod()
  { 
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
       string taskType = "Banana"; // should be an array[i] 
       Type type = Type.GetType("MyService." + taskType);
       var method = type.GetMethod("Test");

       var result = (Task<string>)method.Invoke(null, null);

       tasks.Add(result);
    }    
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
  }
}
```

And for example the 'taskType' above is a class which looks like this:

```
public abstract class Banana
{
    public async Task<string> Test(string input)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why `Banana` is abstract?

Comment: Can you confirm that the method is not found? Or are you encountering a problem when casting to `Task<string>`? Because I'm doing basically the same (except my base class is not abstract), but my problem was the generic `Task<T>`. That doesn't seem to be supported, using `Task` instead helped me.

Comment: @Fildor It's a utility class which makes http requests. There are at least 3 more classes similar to Banana which should be run

Comment: @Fildor Maybe it's better to make Banana non abstract and pass an httpclient object as a parameter to it...

Comment: @BakedInhalf Did you try `Task` instead of `Task<string>`?

Comment: @mu88 No, but I want to be able to return stuff, so I must use Task<T>

Comment: Since you're already using reflection, you can mimic this on your own: await all tasks, use `result.GetType().GetProperty("Result").GetValue(result)` (because the concrete instance is `Task<T>`) and return this.

Answer (score 2):

We've discussed this in the comments, but maybe the following code gives you a better idea.

```cs
public class MyClass
{
  public async Task<string> MyMethod()
  { 
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
       string taskType = "Banana"; // should be an array[i] 
       Type type = Type.GetType("MyService." + taskType);
       var method = type.GetMethod("Test");

       var result = (Task)method.Invoke(null, null);

       tasks.Add(result);
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    var theResult = string.Empty;
    foreach(var task in tasks)
    {
      theResult += (string)task.GetType().GetProperty("Result").GetValue(task);
    }

    return theResult;
  }
}
```

I've written it completely blind and couldn't test it - bear with me!

But the general idea is the following: the concrete async method is of `Task<string>`, but I couldn't find a way to invoke an async generic method. But since every `Task<T>` is a non-generic `Task`, we can cast to it and await it. The additional knowledge that each element within `tasks` is a `Task<string>` allows us to retrieve its property `Result` via reflection.

Comment: I think the problem also was that there was nothing to invoke since the `var result = (Task)method.Invoke(null, null);` will not run because I need an instance of the 'Banana'-class, to pass as an argument to the Invoke method. Interesting discussion! :-)